# Upload video to youtube from S3 using Youtube API

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, youtube, upload

How can i transfer file amazon s3 to youtube using php api, also is there available to set bitrate when uploading.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097105/getting-a-video-from-s3-and-uploading-to-youtube-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a video from S3 and Uploading to YouTube in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097105/getting-a-video-from-s3-and-uploading-to-youtube-in-php)